# An example of a function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ which is continuously differentiable and such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < |x-y|$ for all $x,y \in [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

> (Tao Volume 2, P.152, Exercise 6.6.3) Give an example of a function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ which is continuously differentiable and such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < |x-y|$ for all $x,y \in [a,b]$, but such that $|f'(x)| = 1$ for at least one value of $x \in [a,b]$.

I am struggling to coming up with an example. Could you give me one?

Comment: I think $e^{-x}$ on$ [0,\infty]$ works.

Comment: The question as stated cannot be correct, the less trivial question would probably be "$<|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in[a,b]$ with $x\neq y$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sin(x) $ on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$: $\sin'(0)=\cos(0)=1$, if you allow me to assume $|\sin t| < |t| $ for all $t\neq 0$, then:
$$|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|=2\left|\sin\left(\frac x2 - \frac y2\right) \cos\left(\frac x2 + \frac y2\right) \right |\le 2 \left|\sin\left(\frac x2 - \frac y2\right)\right| < 2\left| \frac x2 - \frac y2\right| = |x-y| $$

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible. If you take $x = y$ then $0< |f(x) - f(y)| < |x - y | = 0 $

$ 0<0$ is a contradiction.

I'm going to assume you meant the inequality holds for all $x \not= y$

So, if we take $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = \frac{x^{2}}{2}$

We have that $ |\frac{x^{2} - y²}{2}| < |x - y| \iff |x+y| < 2$

This is holds because $x,y \in [0,1]$ then $ x + y \leq 2$ and $x + y = 2 \iff x = y = 1$ but $x \not= y \implies x + y < 2$

And $f'(1) = 1$

Comment: This can't be the question, if it was $\le$ then why not just take $f(x)=x$. IMO it should be $<|x-y|$ for all $x\neq y$

Comment: thank you Calvin!

Comment: There I corrected it

Comment: i see it (and did not downvote)